# PyCharm cannot load pandas module

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Somehow my PyCharm cannot import pandas module in Python Console.

```
import pandas
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

And of course, the same error appears when I run a script in my project. As you may notice, I am using an anaconda3 environment. Building and starting a new anaconda environment does not work.

```
/home/work/.conda/envs/siegellab/bin/python3.5 /snap/pycharm-community/169/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py --mode=client --port=45913
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/home/work/phd/protabank'])
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 21:41:56) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 6.5.0
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 21:41:56) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
import os
  ...:os.environ['PYCHARM_DEBUG'] = 'True'
  ...:runfile('/home/work/project/sequence_manager.py', wdir='/home/work/project')
  ...:
Backend Qt5Agg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Interestingly, loading pandas through ipython in PyCharm terminal works.

```
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import pandas

In [2]:
```

The problem does not happen for numpy and os module. Is there any recommendation to make pandas loadable in PyCharm?

Comment: As I recall, there was a known bug with PyCharm and importing packages, especially from  an env.  You probably need to update PyCharm or find the bug on the JetBrains website and implement the fix.

Answer (score 0):

There is a version mismatch. Terminal ipython uses Python 3.5 while that of PyCharm uses Python 3.6.

Reinstalling the environment and matching the python versions solve the problem.